# Get AD-User based on multiple properties

Tags: powershell

I want to look for everyone in the IT department in New york Office. How do I combine the two codes? I **ONLY** want to search users by filtering properties and not -searchbase.

```
Code 1:
get-aduser -filter "department -eq 'IT'" #get everyone from IT department 

Code 2: 
get-aduser -LDAPFilter "(PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName=NewYork)" #get everyone   from NewYorkOffice
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can combine filter statements with boolean operators:

```
get-aduser -filter {department -eq 'IT' -AND PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName -eq 'NewYork'} -Properies ('PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName', 'Department')
```

Comment: If preferred, the LDAP filter syntax would be:  `-LDAPFilter "(&(department=IT)(physicalDeliveryOfficeName=NewYork))"`

Comment: You should also have to add department to `-Properties`

Comment: Yep, thanks Matt. Did it off the cuff. It is fixed now.

Comment: @BaconBits You might as well make your own answer that covers the LDAP venue.